# IIS 7.5 virtual directory cannot load assembly which is referenced in the root web.config

Tags: iis, iis-7.5, web.config, virtual-directory

I've encountered the following problem with the IIS 7.5.

Under root I have a virtual directory which is setup as application running under classic pipeline.

it looks like this

```
    -root (integrated)
    -bin
    -virtualdirectory (classic)
    --bin
    --somevirtualfile.apx
    --web.config
    -somefile.aspx
    -web.config
```

The root site is running as integrated pipeline and references few assemblies which are under root bin folder.

The problem comes when requesting a virtual directory, and assemblies referenced in the root web.config don't exist in the virtual directory bin folder. IIS throws an error unable to load referenced assemblies.

Anyone can shine some light?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I believe the assemblies entries are inherited down the chain of configuration. So, if you do not want your subdirectory application to try to load assemblies that do not exist, you need to add `<remove>` entries for those which do not exist. You would add those in the web.config file in the subdirectory.